# MySQL Temp Table Performance

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my situation:

I am building a product catalog system which has numerous search criteria which can be added by the user, either by direct request or by the user's permissions, location, or other meta-data.

1. There is a main query which is doing the heavy lifting, it is rather large and contains a variable number of subqueries to make the magic happen. The query returns 9 columns, none of which contain much data, and some of which are usually just null.
2. I need access to the resulting data of this query in several other queries that follow it (for example, sorting the result data, applying a secondary layer of filters, pagination, selecting alternate filter options).
3. On the PHP side, I only need the paginated result of 25 items, so I would like to keep my database data in the database.

The solution I am working with is to create a temporary table, and insert/select the data into it.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_table`
(
    `col1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `col2` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `col3` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `col4` decimal(10,2) NULL,
    `col5` decimal(10,2) NULL,
    `col6` decimal(10,2) NULL,
    `col7` decimal(10,2) NULL,
    `col8` decimal(10,2) NULL,
    `col9` tinyint(1) NULL,
    `col10` int(11) NULL,
    `col11` int(11) NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

INSERT INTO `tmp_table` (col1, col2, etc.)
SELECT [...large query]
```

The problem: By itself the large query executes in < 0.3s, however adding the temp table insert pushes the execution up between 3.5s ~ 5.0s

I have tried MEMORY, InnoDB, and MyISAM as the table engine, all with similar results.

I have tried with and without indexes on the temp table, this did not seem to effect the execution time much either.

The execution time is almost the same for a result set of 50 or 500.

My question: Is this approach unsuitable? Are there any MySQL configuration variables I should be looking at to improve performance? Is there better solution that I've overlooked?

Comment: Did you configure InnoDB to use more memory than the default limit of 8MB?

Comment: Yes, innodb_buffer_pool_size is 20GB.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another column for the session ID to you table, and make it non-temporary. Then the first query would just insert its data into this table, and from time to time you would clean it up removing data for expired sessions. This avoids the overhead of creating tables for each request.

Probably, you would delete all session specific data also before you do the insert.

Comment: This was one of the solutions I had considered, however the result set for each request will be different enough that the data will be replaced most of the time.

Comment: As I understood your request was to cache the output of the heavy query for several otehr queries that use it as a base. Maybe even then it will save time, and you could e. g. always delete the data after the last secondary query is done. Especially as you would not have to send the data across to your web server, but could leave them locally in the database.